# Mocked imperative Apex method does not return mocked value

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-object, custom-controller, lwc-jest, mock

My lwc has an input and a button. When I press the button an apex call with the input's value is made. Even though the method is called with the right params, the return value is some sort of empty object

```
const APEX_OBJECTS_LIST = require("./data/objectsList.json");

jest.mock(
  "@salesforce/apex/ObjectController.findObject",
  () => {
    return { default: jest.fn() };
  },
  { virtual: true }
);

async function flushPromises() {
  return Promise.resolve();
}
---
findObject.mockResolvedValue(APEX_OBJECTS_LIST);
const buttonEl = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-button");
buttonEl.click();

await flushPromises();

expect(findObject).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ searchKey: "OBJ-123456" });
expect(findObject).toHaveReturnedWith(APEX_OBJECTS_LIST);
```

```
# Error
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveReturnedWith(expected)

Expected: APEX_OBJECTS_LIST
Received: {}
```

The most helpful answer I found was from [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/328662/lwc-jest-mocking-imperative-apex-and-returning-a-value). I also test other tags that are populated with the mocked list and they are successful. This means that the mocked object does come through but is not "cough" at `toHaveReturnedWith()`.

If I try `toHaveReturnedWith({})` the error is the same, meaning that what is received is not an empty object after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jest documentation has a [.resolves/.rejects](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#resolves--rejects) testing section. Testing this out, it seems the `resolves.toBe()` can help you assert that your resolved promise is what you provided

```javascript
expect(findObject()).resolves.toBe(APEX_OBJECTS_LIST)
```

If the above were to fail, you'll notice the following would be the error

> JestAssertionError: expect(received).resolves.toBe(expected)

Looking at your error message, you can see it's referencing the mock implementation: `jest.fn()`.